# Store magento contact form data in database?

Tags: php, magento

I want to store magento contact form data into database. I don't know basically it posts to which controller?

I want to send email as well store all the data in my custom table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your custom table built create a module in your local pool and extend the `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`. Look at the ticket I submitted in [Magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/adding-a-custom-function-to-insert-contact-forms-to-database-after-post-action-f). the code I use in the post below is from my contact form. Just use the right `$_POST` variable to pass into the custom form.

[See my code here and how to properly extend it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/adding-a-custom-function-to-insert-contact-forms-to-database-after-post-action-f)